# make curtain like behaviour in drawing of lines

Tags: processing

I am new to `Processing.js` and need a little bit support with this issue. I have made a HTML-Canvas animation where I have lines with a curtain like behavior which can be seen here:

[Click](http://super-sized.de/fluxy/)

this is made with a canvas plugin called `Paper.js`
I now want to get similar effect on processing but don't really know how to figure it out. My attempt was:

```
float x;
float y;

void setup() {
   size(1024, 768);
   strokeWeight(2);
   background(0, 0, 0);
}

void mouseMoved() {
   x = mouseX;
   y = mouseY;
}

void draw() {
   background(0);
   line(50, 50, x += x - x/5, y += y - y/5);
   stroke(255, 255, 255);
   line(50, 700, x += x - x/15, y += y - y/15);

   stroke(255, 255, 255);
   line(75, 50, x += x - x/25, y += y - y/25);
   stroke(255, 255, 255);
   line(75, 700, x += x - x/35, y += y - y/35);

   // and so on, would create it within a loop
}
```

So what I am trying to do is basically get the same effect which I have done in HTML and adapt it in Processing.js.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: as a question about porting, you might be better served over at http://codereview.stackexchange.com - the fact that you're listing the same code with different fixed numbers outside of a loop would make it worth getting peer input on how to best achieve things like your paper.js program, efficiently. With that knowledge, implementing the same in Processing becomes easier.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I thought about this too, but the issue I have might be just a logical issue. The numbers does not matter that much, its just to explain what I intend to do. I don't need the code one to one, it's more like I want to achieve kind of the same effect. Something must be working different in Processing, and thats what I basically ask for. Thank you for your tip!

Comment: looking at the paper.js sketch, it's a pretty easy thing to write from scratch It's just an array of `n` historic mouse points that gets shifted by the new mouse coordinate each frame, drawing lines at `width/n` intervals to the corresponding coordinate.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans would it be too cheeky then to ask you for an answer? It would really help to have something to start with, or just showing me what my possible mistake is?

Comment: a little - I would pretty much ignore the paper.js program because it's highly inefficient code, and just write it from sketch. Then again, I am the processing.js maintainer, so this should be something I can do in a few minutes. I'll tack an answer to this post.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans despite my code it would have an advantage for me if I could read your working code and could understand each steps. I would appreciate an answer. Thanks

Comment: I've added a better take as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd strongly recommend ignoring the paper.js and reimplementing this properly. We're seeing a sequence of lines that connect to a historical line of coordinates, based on mouse position, so let's just implement that:

```
class Point {
  float x, y;
  Point(float _x, float _y) { x=_x; y=_y; }}

// our list of historical points
ArrayList<Point> points;

// the horizontal spacing of our lines has fixed interval
float interval;

// how many lines do we want to draw?
int steps = 50;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  // initialise the "history" as just the midpoint
  points = new ArrayList<Point>();
  for (int i=0; i<steps; i++) {
    points.add(new Point(width/2, height/2));
  }
  // compute the horizontal interval, because it's
  // width-dependent. Never hard code dependent values.
  interval = width/(float)steps;
  // the lower we set this, the slower it animates.
  frameRate(60);
}

void draw() {
  // white background, black lines
  background(255);
  stroke(0);
  // for each historic point, draw two
  // lines. One from height 0 to the point,
  // another from height [max] to the point. 
  Point p;
  for (int i=0; i<steps; i++) {
    p = points.get(i);
    line(interval/2 + i*interval, 0, p.x, p.y);
    line(interval/2 + i*interval, height, p.x, p.y);
  }

  // when we move the mouse, that counts as a new historic point
  points.remove(0);
  points.add(new Point(mouseX, mouseY));
}
```

Sketch running in the browser: http://jsfiddle.net/M2LRy/1/

(You could speed this up by using a round-robin array instead of an ArrayList, but ArrayLists are pretty convenient here)

Comment: thank you very much for this! I will take my time to see through it to understand all. But it works fine :)